# Clearing the default empty value in a Winform Combobox of type: DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How do I go about making the default value of the combobox as the first item in the array.

Answer (score 20):

Put this code after you have populated the combo box:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```